# "Of all the stupid things to do!" - elliptical?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, expressions

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary's [article for "all"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/all_1?q=all) contains the following example for the section "of all the..."

> I've locked myself out. Of all the stupid things to do!

According to the article, the meaning of the expression *"of all the..."* is *"to express anger"*.

I understand that the second sentence of the two cited above, since beginning with *"of all the..."*, has the purpose to express anger about having locked theirselves out. But how the rest of this sentence (*"stupid things to do"*) is connected to its beginning and to the first sentence? Is that a kind of an elliptical remark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It suggests a completion :

> Of all the stupid things to do, *locking myself out is the most stupid thing.*

The "obvious" continuation is omitted (ellipsis). "Of" here means "among"

The sentence is also hyperbolic (it uses exaggeration). Therefore it is both elliptic and hyperbolic [maths joke].

Comment: According to this schema, "of all the..." could be used to express admiration, too? Like "I've solved this riddle of the century. Of all the bright things to do!"

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet Perhaps... But it this pattern is usually expressing critisism "Of all the stupid/dumb/annoying/careless things"